# How to improve the performance of an object detector model?

Tags: deep-learning, tensorflow, object-detection

I have few questions regarding improving the performance of my object detection model. When there is color match between person uniform and the background, it becomes difficult for my model to distinguish person from background and detect it. How to overcome this?

I'm using faster rcnn with resnet backbone. The data is taken from a factory, where uniform of the workers is matching with the background color of that factory

In multi-class detection one specific class is not properly being detected, precision value for that class is very low. What can be the reasons behind this and how to overcome the issue?

Comment: very little information is provided in the question to answer it. For example what methods/models do you use for detection? What other procedures are followed which affect the data?

Comment: I'm using faster rcnn with resnet at its backbone as a feature extractor. The data is taken from a factory, where uniform of the workers is matching with the background color of that factory, therefore there is no proper gradient flow. How can I improve this so that the model learns to detect it.

Comment: Maybe increase contrast in images?

Comment: Can you post some sample images where your model is struggling?